# Implementing Password AND Auth Code OAuth2 flow with Spring Security 5.7

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0

I'm working on an authentication service to bridge modern apps that can use the authorization code flow and legacy apps that need to stay with the password flow for now. I understand the downsides of using the password flow, but like I say, it's just to make a better bridge for existing legacy apps until they can be upgraded to a version that has better OAuth2 support.

I want to have both a basic login that uses that to get a token using the password flow that's essentially a server-to-server login on behalf of a user in another app, while also using the same provider for the regular authorization code flow.

The `OAuth2ClientProperties.Registration` has `authorizationGrantType` but it's only a singular value. I could duplicate the provider, but I wouldn't want that presented on the `/login` page, just in the case of a basic request.

I can see how it'd be fairly straightforward to do this with custom code, but it seems like the framework almost does this but I'm getting lost in the details. I'm hoping for a "pure" spring security solution.

Comment: I'm using Spring Security 5.7 spring-security-oauth2-client. I'm going to be overhauling these apps later this year and I'm not wanting to change too much. I'm also hoping to not have to deal with the legacy oauth2 library.

Comment: Then you added the wrong tag for an old EOL framework. I thought you want to use it, to use resource owner grant type. With Spring Security >4 there is no more support for resource owner grant type.

Comment: Not totally true. It was added in 5.2.

Comment: Your are right, Iit is too long ago to remember.

Comment: Is it sure that the a server that can support multiple flows at the same time? If yes you'll have to use a Bean of SecurityFilterChain class.